# Add background-image of background when hovering a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've the following code:

```
<div class="container">
   // some other code
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="#service">service</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The `<a>` links are styled as buttons.
Now I want to achieve, when I hovering the `<a>` link, I will add a background image to the container-div. But each of the `<li>`'s have their own image. So when I hover the "about" link, the container div get's a "about"-image. When I hover the "service" link, the container div get's a "service"-image.

How can I achieve that?

What I already tried:
`.container ul li a:hover .container{ background-image: url('path/to/image) }`
`.container ul li a:hover > .container{ background-image: url('path/to/image) }`
`.container ul li a:hover ~ .container{ background-image: url('path/to/image) }`
`.container ul li a:hover + .container{ background-image: url('path/to/image) }`

WHEN IT IS NOT POSSIBLE WITH ONLY CSS, Is there a way with JavaScript / jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$('.container > ul > li > a').each(function() {
    $(this).hover(function() {
        $('.container').toggleClass(this.hash.replace('#', ''));
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.about { background-image: url('path/to/image1') }
.service { background-image: url('path/to/image2') }
.contact { background-image: url('path/to/image3') }
```

Comment: Is there a way to animate this background change? When I add a background-image transition to the `.containter` class, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible using css alone

```
<div class="container">// some other code
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#about" data-type="about">about</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#service" data-type="service">service</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#contact" data-type="contact">contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

then

```
.container.about{
    background-image: url(...)
}
```

and

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.container li a').hover(function () {
        $('.container').addClass($(this).data('type'))
    }, function () {
        $('.container').removeClass($(this).data('type'))
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zdrqa/)

Comment: Works good, but the solution by Banana-In-Black is slimmer. But +1!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
   // some other code
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#about" id="1">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="#service" id="2">service</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact" id="3">contact</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>




$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#1').hover(function(){
    $('.container').css("background","url(images/pic1.jpg)");  
}, function () {
     $('.container').css("background","'none'");  
});
    $('#2').hover(function(){
    $('.container').css("background","url(images/pic2.jpg)");  
}, function () {
     $('.container').css("background","'none'");  
});
    $('#3').hover(function(){
    $('.container').css("background","url(images/pic3.jpg)");  
}, function () {
     $('.container').css("background","'none'");  
});

 });
```